# Grabbing object instance id from request.POST when using javascript e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, django

I am using a bootstrap modal to list object instances and perform CRUD operations. I wrapped the entire list in a form and pass the id of each individual object instances to the view using buttons names and value, with the aim to manipulate (CRUD) one object instance at a time. When I delete the object without using Javascript, the view works fine, but as soon as I add the line `e.preventDefault();` then the id of the object selected is not captured in the request anymore.

why is that ?

In more detail, the template looks like this:

```
<form
action="{% url 'delete_habit' %}"
method="POST"
id="deleteForm">{% csrf_token %}
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 pb-3">
   <table class="modal-table border" id="habitsTable">
    <tbody>
      {% for habit in habits %}
       <tr class="border js-row-{{habit.id}}">
        <td class="border">
          <img src="{% static 'img/bars_icon.svg' %}">
        </td>
        <td class="text-left border px-3">{{habit.name}}</td>
        <td class="border">
          <button
           id="delete-{{habit.id}}"
           type="submit"
           value="{{habit.id}}"
           name="habit_id"
           class="btn">
               <img src="{% static 'img/minus_icon.svg' %}">
          </button>
         </td>
       </tr>
       {% endfor %}
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

the view:

```
def delete_habit(request):
    habit_id = request.POST.get('habit_id') --> this fails when e.preventDefault()
    data = {'habit_deleted': int(habit_id)}
    habit_to_delete = Habit.objects.filter(id=int(habit_id)).filter(
        user=request.user)
    habit_to_delete.delete()
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

the javascript:

```
var deleteForm = document.getElementById('deleteForm');
if (deleteForm  !== null){
  deleteForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
      var formData = new FormData(deleteForm);
      e.preventDefault();
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open(deleteForm.method, deleteForm.action, true);
      var cookies = parse_cookies();
      request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', cookies['csrftoken']);
      request.onload = function() {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
          var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
          removeRow("js-row-" + data.habit_deleted);
        };
      };
      request.send(formData);
  });
};
```

The line `e.preventDefault()` seem to be the culprit as, when I add this line in the JS, the request then does not return the id of the habit selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @GrandPhuba and a very wise friend, I changed the behaviour of the table to use anchors:

The table:

```
<table class="modal-table border" id="habitsTable">
  <tbody>
  {% for habit in habits %}
    <tr class="habit-{{habit.id}}">
      <td class="text-left border px-3">{{habit.name}}</td>
      <td>
        <a class="delete-link"
        href="{% url 'delete_habit' habit.id %}"
        data-habit="{{habit.id}}" onkeyup="">
          <img src="{% static 'img/minus_icon.svg' %}">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The javascript:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName("delete-link");

  var removeHabit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var habit_id = this.getAttribute("data-habit");
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", this.href, true);
    var cookies = parse_cookies();
    request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', cookies['csrftoken']);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.send(JSON.stringify({
        habit_id: habit_id
    }));
    removeRow("habit-"+ habit_id);
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].addEventListener('click', removeHabit, false);
  }
```

the view:

```
def delete_habit(request, habit_id):
    habit_to_delete = Habit.objects.get(pk=habit_id)
    habit_to_delete.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's fix the problems one by one:

#### Issue 1: Empty Data

For some reason I think `new FormData(deleteForm)` is resulting to an empty object, so try serializing the form manually

```
function formToJson(formElement){
    var inputElements = formElement.getElementsByTagName("input"),
        jsonObject = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++){
        var inputElement = inputElements[i];
        jsonObject[inputElement.name] = inputElement.value;

    }
    return JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
}
```

Then in your HTML, change the following from:

```
<td class="border">
    <button id="delete-{{habit.id}}" type="submit" value="{{habit.id}}" name="habit_id" class="btn">
        <img src="{% static 'img/minus_icon.svg' %}">
    </button>
</td>
```

To:

```
<td class="border">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{habit.id}}" name="habit_id">
    <button id="delete-{{habit.id}}" type="submit" class="btn">
        <img src="{% static 'img/minus_icon.svg' %}">
    </button>
</td>
```

Then in your listener:

```
request.send(JSON.stringify(formToJson(deleteForm)))
```

#### Issue 2: Incorrect HTTP Method

The `method` parameter of `XMLHttpRequest.open()` is case-sensitive (must be in all caps), while `deleteForm.method` is in lower case.

Try the following instead:

`request.open(deleteForm.method.toUpperCase(), deleteForm.action, true);`

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer GrandPhuba. Sadly it does not work either. The command `deleteForm.method` indeed prints in lower case but the method `upper()` does not work. I used `.toUpperCase()` instead which prints the method in capital letter but it still did not fix the issue sadly.

Comment: For some reason I think new FormData(deleteForm) is resulting to an empty object. Can you try inspecting its value (`formData`). If it's empty, try the solution I added at the top. If it's not empty or doesn't fix your issue, let me know and I'll look more into your issue

Comment: You are right @GrandPhuba, printing `formData` returns an empty object. Now I tried your potential solution and printed `JSON.stringify(jsonObject)` after passing `deleteForm` as argument to your `formToJson` method but it returns only the csrf token sadly ( aligned with the value of the POST request, which is the point of the function I presume).

Comment: @Ben Updated my answer. I checked your HTML as well, and saw the value is in the button. While this is valid, my function is only processing `input` tags only. You can either move the form value from the button to an input tag (like in my update where I used a hidden field), or you can modify the function so it processes buttons as well

Comment: Hi @GrandPhuba, thanks for your help so far ! 1) It seems adding the hidden input in the form only selects the last habit on submit, 2) It also seems that e.preventDefault() prevents the view from deleting the object still. Thanks so much for sharing your clues so far ! I m starting to think that using form might not be the correct option so will try to execute the same result using anchor - please see my edit above.

Comment: Hi @Ben, I'll check your updates, but at a quick glance, if you have multiple inputs with the same name in the same form, it will use the last value (unless the inputs are `type=radio`). The solution here is to 1. Move the `<form ...> </form>` tag inside the for loop and update your code the listener binds to all forms, or 2. Update your code so it fetches the value exclusively from the hidden input that is a sibling of that button (in case you put that hidden input next to the button). Either way, you'll have to update your code so it strategically gets the data from the right element.